# Hide unassigned (linux) partition from explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

I just set up a usb stick with multiple primary partitions and gpt partition table. The four partitions are Efi, Linux (encrypted), FAT32, Veracrypt (Encrypted).

Plugging in the USB stick into my windows pc, 3 partitions show up in explorer with letters assigned to them, the linux and veracrypt partitions are shown as not formatted.

In the disk management utility, no drive letters are assigned to the linux and veracrypt partitions, and I'm trying to make windows ignore / not show those two partitions in explorer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mountvol` tool in `cmd.exe` to delete the mountpoint, don't worry your data is safe we ara just taking away the letter.

First open a `cmd` prompt as admin. Then type `mountvol` and hit enter, you should be seeing the long name of your partitions and their mountpoint(Eg `E:\`) at the end. Now type `mountvol X:\ /P` where `X:\` is the mointpoint of the unit you want to hide.

To assign a mountpoint just type `mountvol X:\ \\?\Volumne{some-long-thingy}\`

Cheers.

EDIT: Sometimes, I don't know why, in some machines you need to run a `powershell` terminal with administrator rights, then run `cmd` throught that and then work with `mountvol`, it's weird but it gets the job done.

Comment: I had to switch the arguments of `mountvol` around to `mountvol X:\ /P` but then it worked like a charm!

Comment: I'll edit the answer for posterity

Comment: `mountvol X: /P` also worked.