# Hide LUKS partition on USB drive from Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, gpt, luks

Following advice given on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209397/where-do-i-ask-questions-about-the-windows-os I am posting my question here

For my 16 GB USB drive I created a GPT with 2 partitions.

- The first partition is formatted as `NTFS` and is intended for general purpose file exchange.
- The second partition is formatted `ext4` inside a LUKS container (not sure that is the right term to use here) which is intended to transfer rather sensitive data between trusted (mainly my) workstations.

Now, when plugging the device in a Windows 10 machine, Windows seems to not be capable of handling the encrypted partition and suggests to format it which is undesired behavior. Is it possible to configure the drive in such a way that Windows will not try to assign a drive letter / mount it / suggest to format it regardless on which machine I plug it in?

There was a similar question asked at [Hide unassigned (linux) partition from explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/1438043/hide-unassigned-linux-partition-from-explorer) which helped the user because he only needed to hide the partition on one particular Windows computer. I however require it to be hidden for all Windows machines the stick is possibly plugged into

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've had success with setting Microsoft's "hidden" attribute on the GPT partitions in question.

*Always use extreme caution when messing with your partition tables. Back stuff up.*

1. `gdisk /dev/sdc` replacing `/dev/sdc` with the disk in question.
2. `p` to list partitions.
3. `x` to enter expert mode.
4. `a` to set attributes.
5. Enter the partition number.
6. `62` to set the "hidden" attribute.
7. Enter to stop setting attributes.
8. `w` to write partition table.

Comment: There seem to be two candidates: `62: hidden` and `63: do not automount`. What is the difference?