# Protect USB key against formatting? Avoid unfortunate formatting of LUKS encrypted pen-drive

Tags: usb, filesystems, encryption, usb-flash-drive, luks

I notice that when I insert my LUKS-encrypted pen-drive into Windows (which is not meant to work), I get a message inviting me to format the pen-drive, and **the option to format the disk is preselected**:

[image]

Now I fear that my pen-drive will get into the hands of a non-tech-savvy co-worker using Windows who would click the highlighted button and format my USB key without thinking it, causing some data-loss I would prefer to avoid.

**Is there a way to protect a USB key from being formatted?**

Alternatively, does write-protecting the drive prevent formatting from Windows specifically? In this case however, it would be a hassle to always disable and re-enable the write protection, unless this can be automatised easily on my own computer.

I personally mainly use Ubuntu 21.04 (and Manjaro).
The USB key is currently formatted with ext4+LUKS.

Thanks!

PS: I finally may have found something worth trying: [Hide LUKS partition on USB drive from Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1504318/hide-luks-partition-on-usb-drive-from-windows-10?rq=1)

Comment: You do, of course, have at least another two copies of this drive…?

Comment: @Tetsujin - I have another copy of the content, but I'd prefer to avoid such problems, especially because I may work for several hours before backing up. So even with a copy, I may lose some fresh work that's more recent than the backup...

Comment: Just an idea, I'm not sure if it will work: make sure it's partitioned with GPT and the partition has an exotic GUID different than [basic data partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition). If you're using GParted, that would be equivalent to unchecking the `msftdata` flag I think.